# Spring Load A Bean Before Any Other Bean

Tags: java, spring

I have a requirement that I want to initialize a bean before any other bean in my application context. One way to do is to use "depends-on" on every other bean but its too verbose as I have many beans in my application-context.

Is there any other way to do this. I have read abt implementing ServletContext for this but I dont think this will work as this has nothing to do with Spring.

Please let me know your thoughts on it.

Thanks,
Raunak

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your bean comes first in your context.xml and it will be instantiated first. You can make a simple test to verify.